# как встроить функционал Git в программу на C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, git

как встроить функционал Git в программу на C++/Qt ?

Comment: https://libgit2.github.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) - библиотеку на C, разработанную специально для этой цели.